# Generating a nice amount of range elements between two numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, range

I'm trying to figure out a good way to write a little "algorithm", which would be able to find a mathematical a range between these two numbers:

```
Let's suppose maximum number is 1500 and minimum number would be 1;
```

By performing some sort of mathematical formula, method would be able to determine that best range between these two numbers is lets say 100;

So range would be:

`100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500`

Other example:

Maximum is 10, minimum 1;

Best range would be (let's say):

```
2,4,6,8,10
```

Are there any libraries in c# which offer this kind of solution or is there some neat mathematical formula used to determine this?

P.S. Guys there can be a remainder in the number as well...

I'm guessing I can divide the maximum number into let's say 7 fixed groups, and then just add up the divided number until I get the max value , no ?

Okay guys I've figured out an idea, lets suppose maximum number is a floating point number and is: 1326.44..., while the minimum is 132.5

```
I'm going to say that maximum range can be 7... So what I can do is divide 1326.44 with 7 and I'll get 189.49
```

So the first amount in range is:

```
var ranges = new[] { 132.5, 189.5 ... /*Now I just need to dynamically somehow add the rest of the range elements?*/ };
```

Comment: So basically you want find a complex math expression that simply do a division without remainder?

Comment: @Tinwor Yes there can be a remainder, I forgot to mention ... Sry

Comment: I'm guessing I can divide the maximum number into let's say 6 fixed groups, and then just add up the divided number until I get the max value , no ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's up to you the decision in how many group you want split your population

Comment: @Tinwor Let's say it's 7, I've edited my answer... I just need to somehow now get the rest of the elements values dynamically

Comment: Please read [ask]. Stack Overflow isn't really suited to brainstorming. It's for questions that don't change every minute as you come up with ideas.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this is final question , the one in the end wher I wrote the code... I'm not sure how to add the rest of the elements into the list until the maximum number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually super easy. You have a min range value and a max range value, and you want a particular number of items in your range. Therefore, you simply need to calculate a step value, and then add that recursively to the minimum value until you're at the maximum value. For example:

```
var min = 132.5;
var max = 1326.44;
var count = 7;

var step = (max - min) / count;

var items = new List<double>();
for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step)
{
    items.Add(i);
}
```